# Android Fragment ошибка с обработкой OnClick

Tags: android

В чем может быть ошибка запуска приложения? Ошибка возникла при добавлении обработчика кнопки. Вот код:

```
package com.drusilovihi.tabbedapp_b1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Mail m ;
    private ImageButton imgSend;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        m = new Mail("*************", "*******");
        imgSend.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imgSend.setOnClickListener(this);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    }


    public void sendEmail(View view){
        String[] toArr = {"toemail1@domain1.tld"}; // This is an array, you can add more emails, just separate them with a coma
        m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
        m.setFrom("fromEmail@domain.tld"); // who is sending the email
        m.setSubject("subject");
        m.setBody("your message goes here");

        try {
            //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/myPicture.jpg");  // path to file you want to attach
            if(m.send()) {
                // success
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // failure
                Toast.makeText(getActivity() ,"Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // some other problem
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Нажата кнопка.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sendEmail(v);
    }
}
```

Стэктрейс:

> 06-17 17:56:10.732 13330-13330/com.drusilovihi.tabbedapp_b1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067‌​) android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248‌​)

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте текст ошибки, а так же StackTrace.

Comment: 06-17 17:56:10.732 13330-13330/com.drusilovihi.tabbedapp_b1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)

Comment: или подскажите пример реализации smtp client android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить кнопку так:

```
imgSend.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

Но таким способом можно получить виджет только в активити. В фрагмегте нужно сначала получить `View` самой разметки через инфлейт, потом искать уже в этом `View` свой виджет.

Код в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536110/177345) . Получаем разметку в `rootView`, потом ищем свою кнопку в этом `rootView`, а не в вакууме, как у вас сейчас

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

    imgSend = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imgSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    m = new Mail("*************", "*******");

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: пробовал 3 способа обработчика и при всех ошибка запуска приложения...